# How do I process POSTed data from the X-Editable plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

There is a plugin called X-editable that uses a click to change AJAX query to a database. The doc's to me are almost pure gibberish other then how to apply the editable content. I've never dealt with AJAX before. The doc page in question can be found [Here](http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/docs.html)

So my main issue is, how am I posting to a file here? I tried using the url: setting in the function.

```
$('#username').editable({
type: 'text',
pk: 1,
url: '/post', // Is this where I put my POST url?
title: 'Enter username'
});
```

I understand I should be posting what did I try, but I don't know where to begin with AJAX, but this plugin would be the best thing to have for my project.

Comment: Man, you weren't kidding about those docs, it totally glosses over the server-side of things.  Your guess about `url` being the URL to the script to accept the data seems to be correct, though.  Why not create a simple script that dumps the contents of `$_POST` somewhere to see what it throws at you?  That should give you a starting point.

Comment: the X-editable have nothing to do with a database. It will make a call using the POST verb over your server and you have to write a script in any language you'r server support to respond to that post, and there, if you want, you can make a query over your database.

Comment: @Charles Glad it wasn't just me haha, I will try that now and get back to you.

Comment: @jachguate Well from what I understand it looks for an HTTP status of OK for it to initiate the change and the value to change, so this may be a bit tricky, if I were to make a query using the PDO library  how could I make sure I get that HTTP status back? Those docs really kill any thought I have, but the idea and look of it is awesome =/

Comment: @Charles Ok, so I tried that, since the plugin only will send some kind of response back is when it the page returns a 200 OK response, I just simply tried echoing my $_POST variable, it worked in a sense, it returned the 200 OK response thus changing what I sent the POST as. Hope that makes sense, so ultimately, as long as I am sending POST data to a working sql query script that will return a 200 OK response, I should be all set...I have a very bad feeling I will run into another issue though with how I am going to lay out my foreach loop using the inline query method. Anyways, thanks :P

Comment: @necro for a HTTP 200 status, you just have to point to a valid URL script and in that script do your database update. If something goes wrong with the update, you change the status to other (for example, 500 - Internal server error) and print some message to the output. If all goes well, you have nothing else to do, as the webserver itself will return the 200 (OK) status, and the output is ignored. So, just print a blank space if you want.

Answer (score 1):

First off, yes the url is where the data is posted to.  I have only used this plugin with Yii using the Yii extension, but I suspect it works the same way in general. There are going to be three things posted for a single field request.  The name (the name html attribute of the field), value (the value of the field), and pk (the primary key which you specify in the editable function that is called on the field.)

```
<input name="username" value="myName" id="username" type="text">

$(function(){
    $('#username').editable({
        url: 'mysite.com/post',
        title: 'Enter username',
        pk: 3
    });
});
```

Will post the following to mysite.com/post:

```
array(
    'name' => 'username',
    'value' => 'myName',
    'pk' => 3
)
```

You can call the editable() function on a class as well as an id and specify the PK of the item to update to submit a whole form at once, although you will have to do a little more digging.  Looking at the Yii extension would likely prove very helpful to you - http://x-editable.demopage.ru - it at least give you some clues.  It also includes all of the server side logic.  It should shed light on how it all works.

That's the gist of Editable, it covers the front-end and you need to make the server side stuff yourself.  If nothing else use something like Firebug to see what it is actually posting, use the front-end docs (which are actually quite good) to get it posting what you want it to be posting, and from there it should be no problem.